# How to debug a VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to write an extension for VSCode, however I'm having all sorts of problems in that part of the extension doesn't appear to be recognised.

The extension is in two parts, a grammar and languages part -- this is recognised and is working well.

The second part is a debugger, but I cannot get VSCode to see this. There is obviously an error somewhere in my `package.json`, but I cannot find an error message anywhere.

Is there anyway to validate the `package.json` file? Or the solution as a whole? Hitting F5 starts up a child VSCode, but no errors. Looking in the extensions tab, it doesn't show that there is a debugger in the extension, so it must be the wrong configuration?

Comment: Is your extension activated? The debugger config is only available after that.

Comment: I've managed to get it working, but only with a huge amount of trial an error, and I couldn't say what exactly was wrong. I can't find a way to see whats going through stdin\stdout, which is really hurting the ability to test! But thats for another question I guess.